# Getting Custom Column from IQueryable DB First Approach EF

Tags: wcf, linq-to-entities, odata, wcf-data-services, wcf-data-services-client

I am working on Database First Approach in Entity Framework where I have to retrieve specific columns from the Entity.

```
Public IQueryable<Entity.Employees> GetEmployeeName(String FName,String LName)
{
     var query = (from s in Employees
                  where s.firstName = FName && s.lastName = LName
                  select new {s.firstName, s.middleName});
     return query;
}
```

Here return statement is throwing an error where it seems that its not matching with `Employees` (entity) columns. Could you please help me in sorting out this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use == for comparison, also you need to use dynamic type as return type since you are returning a custom anonymous type. Try this

```
Public IQueryable<dynamic> GetEmployeeName(String FName,String LName)
{
var query=(from s in Employees
where s.firstName==FName && s.lastName==LName
select new {s.firstName,s.middleName});
return query.AsQueryable();
}
```

Finally you will use it like below, keep in mind that intelisense won't work on dynamic object.

```
var query = GetEmployeeName("Jake", "Smith");
            List<dynamic> results = query.ToList();
            foreach (dynamic result in results)
            {
                string fristName = result.FirstName;
                string lastName = result.MiddleName;
            }
```

Comment: I have modified to == but the issue i am facing is in Entity.Employees we have 4 columns but the var query i want only 2 columns in the select statement. So I am getting the error as below:                     'Anonymous Types:
 a is new {}

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable'<<anonymous type:string firstName,string middleName>>' to'System.Linq.IQueryable<Entity.Employees>'.An explicit conversion exists(are you missing a cast?)'

Comment: I just updated my post. Since you are returning anonymous type you need to use dynamic type as return type. Alternatively you can create a custom wrapper type with two fields FirstName and MiddleName and return that instead. This will allow you to have intelisense working when get data back from result.

Comment: I am trying to access this method method [link](http://localhost:1985/Employee.svc/GetEmployeeName?FName='Jake'&LName='Smith') but  getting error. I want to get the specific columns instead of entire entity columns.Could you please suggest or provide a sample snippet how to achieve this.Thanks in Advance.